# Entity in a Windows Service

Tags: entity-framework, windows-services

I built a windows service that uses entity to obtain some data from a remote database. To eliminate possible permission issues I have the service running as my user account. When the database context is initialized I get the following error:

> ERROR The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid.

Which usually means the the app.config is not present; however, I added the app.config to the application directory of the service. Any ideas as to why it cannot connect?

Comment: Does the app config file have the same name as the exe or dll for the windows service?

Comment: Have you debugged it? Perhaps the the connection info is not being picked up correctly.

Comment: One thing I always do with Windows Services (nowadays - after learning the hard way) is copy the code verbatim into a console application and then stepping through the code.  Let me tell you, it makes debugging so much easier.

Comment: Do you have the EntityFramework connection string in the app.config of the windows service? also how are you testing the service? are you calling it from a console/windows application?

Comment: I didn't put the connection string in the service config, I just copied the app.config from the entity project. Once I put the connection string in the service.exe.config everything worked. Thanks for the help!